# Why these lines are necessary for swing application?

Tags: java, object, netbeans

```
public class MedicalCenter {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                new Login().setVisible(true);         <----------
                new TimeAndDate().setVisible(true);   <----------
            });

        }
    }
```

Are these lines used just to start showing main windows of swing application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new keyword is always used while creating objects

Answer (score 0):

They do create objects but you didn't kept their reference.

So you cannot access those objects later on if you want to.